# ScheduledExecutorService schedule is not working

Tags: android

I have service that run the next code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService timer ;
timer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(), 15*60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
But from some reason it is not working.
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Many thanks,
Keren

Answer (score 0):

look out to make sure you are not destroying the ScheduledExecutorService reference holder object before the time of execution